# How do you get items out of a Future and pass those items back as Ok(Json.toJson(items))?

Tags: scala, playframework

Hi there I am trying to get some items out of a database in my backend microservice and pass these to my frontend microservice to display them. I am struggling to get these items out of the Future and then do Ok(Json.toJson(items)) in my Action method for the frontend to call.

Get all items in database: (in my DB connector)

```
def getProducts(): Future[List[MusicProduct]] =
    musicDB.flatMap(_.collection("products")
      .find(Json.obj())
      .cursor[MusicProduct]()
      .collect[List](-1, Cursor.FailOnError[List[MusicProduct]]()))
```

Controller action method for the frontend to call:

```
def getProducts: Action[AnyContent] = Action { implicit request ⇒
  val products: Option[List[MusicProduct]] = productDBConnector.getProducts.map {
      products =>
        if (products.nonEmpty) {
          Some(products)
        } else {
          None
        }
    }

    products.fold(InternalServerError)(prods => Ok(Json.toJson(prods)))
  }
```

This returns a type mismatch error as the val products is still a Future. How do I get out of the Future, Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch the controller to async `Action.async` when dealing with futures https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaAsync

```
def getProducts: Action[AnyContent] = Action.async { implicit request ⇒
  val products: Future[Option[List[MusicProduct]]] = productDBConnector.getProducts.map {
      products =>
        if (products.nonEmpty) {
          Some(products)
        } else {
          None
        }
    }

    products.fold(InternalServerError)(prods => Ok(Json.toJson(prods)))
  }
```

or use `await` on future result (not recommended for production use)

Comment: Thank you, I solved it with your help ```def getProducts: Action[AnyContent] = Action.async { implicit request ⇒
    productDBConnector.getProducts.map {
      products =>
        if (products.nonEmpty) {
          Ok(Json.toJson(products))
        } else {
          Ok("There were no products in the database")
        }
    }
  }```